# Carrige return, tabs with the put statement

Tags: sas

I want to use the data step `put` statement to write some html and javascript code. While I can have the resulting html file look the way I want in the browser, I don't know how to have the code be easy to read both in SAS EG and the resulting file.

I would like the resulting file to have carrige returns, tabs etc, but would like to avoid adding quotation marks to every line. Also, I need it to run in a macro. I've included some attempts below. Is it an easy way to combine the readable results of ex. 2 and ex. 3 with the coidng ease of ex. 1, like an option to set?

```
/*  Ex 1: Easy to read in SAS EG, but no tabs or carrige returns in html-file*/
data _null_;
    file "C:\Test\test1.html" encoding="utf-8" ;
    put "   Some code
            Some code on a new line
                Some indented code";
run;

/*  Ex 2: Tabs and line breaks in html file, but far more cumbersome to write in SAS EG.*/
data _null_;
    file "C:\Test\test2.html" encoding="utf-8";
    put @4  "Some code" /
        @4  "Some code on a new line" /
        @8  "Some indented code";
run;

/*  Ex 3: Easy to read and write in SAS EG, reads well in html file. But won't run in a macro, and resolving macro variables is more trouble than with the methods above.*/
data _null_;
    input  ;
    file "C:\Test\test3.html" encoding="utf-8";
    put _infile_;
datalines;
Some code
Some code on a new line
    Some indented code
;
run;
```

Comment: What's so different about #1 and #2 in SAS EG?

Comment: test1.html is written on a single line, so it needs to be reformatted to be readable. test2.html reads fine as is. And the quotations etc in #2 is ok in a short, stylized example, but gets messy in real code,

Comment: Did you look at `PROC STREAM`?

Comment: No, but I definitely will now.

Comment: Yeah, having read and tested a bit, it really seems like `PROC STREAM` is the way to go. I came looking for something like an option, so it is the solution i didn't know I was looking for.

Comment: Post what you did using proc stream as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For number 3 you can used PARMCARDS and RESOLVE function.

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
parmcards4;
Some code
Some code on a new line &sysdate
    Some indented code
;;;;


%macro main;
   data _null_;
      infile FT15F001;
      input;
      file "C:\Test\test3.html" encoding="utf-8";
      _infile_ = resolve(_infile_);
      put _infile_;
      run;
   %mend;
%main;
```

Comment: very interesting!

Comment: @AllanBowe how do you mean?

Comment: It's a nice solution. Parmcards was new to me. But it is still only possible to have the data _null_ step in a macro, not the whole thing?

Comment: PARMCARDS is not documented in the "Dictionary of SAS Statements" I found this in the documentation for the PARMCARDS option.
SAS writes all data lines after the PARMCARDS (or PARMCARDS4) statement to the file until it encounters a delimiter line of either one or four semicolons. The file is then closed and made available to the procedure to read. There is no parsing or macro expansion of the data lines.

Comment: @RuneS you CAN put the whole program just as I wrote it in a autocall library and it will work.   AUTOCALL is fancy %INC and the code does not violate the rules for %INC.

Comment: @data_null_ - interesting that it is possible to use cards in open code, never seen this.  @RuneS - correct, it is not possible to put cards lines in macro.  If you must have data in macro, you will need to use `proc sql; insert into ` type syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A comment from Tom suggested I should use `PROC STREAM`. This proved way easier than variations on the use of put-statements. A simplified example doesn't quite do it justice, but this proc makes it possible to write this kind of code without the tedium of getting quoting right. I still need to use `&streamDelim newline;` for line breaks, but that's a small price to pay. Example of current setup;

```
/*  Ex 4. Proc stream*/
%macro chartx();
%let cr=%str(&streamDelim newline;);
Some code                       &cr
Some code on a new line         &cr
Some code on a new line, with resolved macro variable &sysdate &cr
    some indented code &cr
%do i=1 %to 1;
Some code from a loop
%end;
%mend;

%macro makepage();

filename testfile "C:\Test\test4.html";

proc stream outfile=testfile;
BEGIN
%chartx
;;;;
%mend;
%makepage
```